# Load certificate previosly imported manually [ANDROID] [HTTPS]

Tags: java, android, https

I added a self signed-certificate (https) manually in Settings-> Security-> Trusted certificates.

And if i try to access to my server using google chrome runs OK (previosly accept message). But in my Android application, using HttpsURLConnection class,crashes.

This is my code:

```
try {
            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpsURLConnection conn;

            conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(timeOut);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            StatusCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.i(TAG_GET, "Status Code: " + StatusCode);

            InputStream body = null;

            try {
                body = conn.getInputStream();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                body = conn.getErrorStream();
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I think that I need load certificates installed on my device, but how can I do?

Thanks